# Scroll event in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div with a scrollbar in it. Now I want to get an event, that triggers every time, the user scrolls.

Is that possible in AngularJS, or do I have to use jQuery for that?

**Edit:**
I came up with following so far:

```
// JS
.directive('scroll', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs){

        angular.element(element).bind("scroll", function(){
            console.log(1);
        });
    };
});

// HTML
<div class="wrapper" style="height: 1550px" scroll>
[...]
</div>
```

But that does not work (I don't see any logs in my Firebug-Console).

Answer (score 16):

Solution for Angular 1.6:

```
.directive("scroll", function () {
return {
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("wheel", function() {
         console.log('Scrolled below header.');
      });
  }
}
```

})

Use "wheel" instead of "scroll". It takes me few hours to find.

Comment: We should use `angular.element(document)` instead of `angular.element('html')` : )

Answer (score 4):

You would be using jquery for adding the event listener, and maybe inside an angularjs directive to attach it to an element.

page.html:

```
<div my-scroller>
```

myscroller.js:

```
app.directive('myScroller', function(){

    return {

        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
            $(elem).on('scroll', function(evt){
               console.log(evt.offsetX + ':' + evt.offsetY);
            });
        }

    }

});
```

Edit: of course you don't even need to use jquery. Angular's jqLite suffices for this, you would just call element without the jquery wrapping:

```
elem.on('scroll', ...
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't necessarily use jQuery, it's using jqLite (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: @NevilleS correct, I wrapped it inside $() so it uses jQuery.

Comment: You don't need to though; jqLite provides the `on()` method as well (with some restrictions), avoiding the need to include jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @frankies. I edited my post and added the code, I already tried.
If there is any chance to do it without jQuery, I would like to it without.

Answer (score 1):

Sergey's answer helped me a little, but what ended up working for me was this:

```
.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
   return {
      link: function() {
         angular.element($window).bind("wheel", function() {
            console.log('Scrolling');
         });
      }
   }
})
```