# Angular directive to detect scrolling within an ng-repeat container

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my Angular app, I've created a simple directive to do something on scroll, based on the answer provided to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588300/scroll-event-in-angularjs).

Here is the code to my `onScroll` directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('proverbial')
        .directive('onScroll', Directive);

    Directive.$inject = [ '$document' ];
    function Directive($document) {

        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {  
            element.bind('scroll', function(e) {
                console.warn(e)
                if (element[ 0 ].scrollTop + element[ 0 ].offsetHeight >= element[ 0 ].scrollHeight) {
                    scope.$apply(attr.onScroll);
                }
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

This is to be used in the following HTML template:

```
<div class="absolute" on-scroll="vm.totalDisplayed += 100">
    <span class="card hover"
    ng-repeat="proverb in vm.proverbs | limitTo: vm.totalDisplayed">
        <a>{{proverb.text | maxLength: 90}}</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

The intention is to keep increasing `vm.totalDisplayed` on page scroll, to create an effect similar to lazy-loading.

However, when I scroll down to the end of what has been already loaded with ng-repeat, nothing happens. The `console.warn(e)` never triggers.

On the browser console I can see that the containing `<div class="absolute" on-scroll="vm.totalDisplayed += 100">` does indeed scroll up past the browser's window.

What's missing?

Comment: `attr.onScroll` is a string that won't get executed doing :

     `scope.$apply(attr.onScroll);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite @Tom pointing out correctly that I had a syntatic error in my directive, it turns out that that wasn't the issue.

The issue was that the element to which I attached my directive was not actually being scrolled due to its CSS styling, so I had to tweak the code slightly, by binding `scroll` to `$document` instead:

```
( function () {

    'use strict';

    var angular = window.angular || {};

    angular
        .module( 'proverbial' )
        .directive( 'onDocumentScroll', Directive );

    Directive.$inject = ['$document'];

    function Directive( $document ) {

        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };

        return directive;

        function link( scope, element, attrs ) {
            $document.bind( 'scroll', function () {
                if ( $document.scrollTop() - scope.vm.latestThreshold >= element[0].offsetHeight ) {
                    scope.vm.latestThreshold += $document.scrollTop();
                    scope.$apply( attrs.onDocumentScroll );
                }
            } );
        }
    }
} )();
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a minor mistake in your code:

```
if (element[ 0 ].scrollTop + element[ 0 ].offsetHeight >= element[ 0 ].scrollHeight) {
    scope.$apply(attr.onScroll);
}
```

`attr` is undefined. Should be `attrs`.

Furthermore, I can't reproduce the problem. I've created a Plunker from your code and the warning shows just fine. Only thing what I find weird is that I couldn't get `vm.totalDisplayed += 100` to work. `vm.totalDisplayed = vm.totalDisplayed + 100` worked though.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ooMFG4ZAZzxJf9zuChyA