# Scroll event in AngularJS using $scope.$on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, events

Is there a way to catch the event scrolling the page does **inside a controller**?
I have this on my component's controller $onInit:

```
$scope.$on('scroll', function() {
        console.log('Something something');
      });
```

I have only seen ways to do this using .bind() on a directive, like here: [Scroll event in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588300/scroll-event-in-angularjs)

I have been lurking the official guide and I have found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a attribute to the directive you linked to to take in a function from your controller to call when the scroll happens

```
.directive("scroll", function () {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope : {
         "onScroll" : "&onScroll"
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind("wheel", function() {
         scope.onScroll();
      });
  }
}
});
```

Then in your template you would pass it in the attribute value

```
<ul scroll on-scroll="myController.onScroll()">
</ul>
```

Comment: After some investigation, I found out that is impossible to catch this event outside a directive. This works as well: 


`link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var theElementWithScroll = element[0];
      theElementWithScroll.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
         scope.onScroll();
      });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularJS's `$element` to do this properly.

```
angular.element($element).on('scroll', function() {
  console.log('Something something');
});
```

in a controller, `$element` is the element in the DOM that the controller is bound to.